# Send ios debug build errors with testFlight

Tags: codenameone

I send ios to debug build with ios.testFlight=true but got errors.

ld: framework not found LocalAuthentication.frameworkSystemConfiguration
ld: framework not found LocalAuthentication.frameworkSystemConfiguration
clang: clang: error: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:

The following build commands failed:
Ld /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build3940251568321742808xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisionClass/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/VisionClass.app/VisionClass normal (in target 'VisionClass' from project 'VisionClass')
(1 failure)
Ld /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build3940251568321742808xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisionClass/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/VisionClass.app/VisionClass normal (in target 'VisionClass' from project 'VisionClass')
(1 failure)
Process return code is 65
Failed xcodebuild step

Thanks.

Comment: With iOS the error message isn't always at the bottom so we need the full log to help you with these sort of errors.

Comment: How do I send you the log file? It's a 18 MB file.

Comment: Just send a link

Comment: https://cloud.codenameone.com/build/downloadResult?i=2c234518-30c4-409d-a268-bba5ab7947dd&b=da6720a1-7a71-4a93-8902-96733cfe31ea&n=error.txt

Comment: I generate a new cn1 project for rebuilding my code.
Build successfully.